# Read and compare argument with argv - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv

I want to pass an argument and from it make a condition, follow the example below:

```
import argparse

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--database", required=True, help="path to the 
database images")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

if  (args == "mnist"):

    print('Hello!')
```

And then in the terminal I enter with:

```
python argv.py --database mnist
```

But my code simply does nothing. What am I doing wrong? How could I do this correctly?

Comment: What does `print(args)` give you?

Comment: @PeterWood, **{'database': 'mnist'}**

Comment: `if args['database'] == "mnist":`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, this worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Why bother with `vars`? With the namespace you get you can just access `parsed.database`. And next time check what you're actually comparing before asking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `vars` on the Argparse NameSpace gives you a dict. You should compare the `database` argument now parsed as Key `'database'` in the dict returned by `vars`:

```
if args['database'] == "mnist":
    print('Hello!')
```

Comment: This may be closable on grounds of a typological/nonrepro error... should it be answered?

Answer (score 0):

by using the cli_args_system you can solve in this way,
first, install the lib with:

```
linux: pip3 install cli-args-system
windows: pip install cli-args-system
```

after:

```py
from sys import exit
from cli_args_system import Args


args = Args()


help = args.flags_content('help','h')
if help.exist():
    HELP_TEXT = '-db/-database  path to the database images'
    print(HELP_TEXT)
    exit(0)


#get the flag
database = args.flag_str('database','db')
#means that the flag dont exist 
if not database:
    print('database is required');exit(0)


if database == 'mnist':
    print('hello')
```